# Angular nested component tags not showing

Tags: angular

I have 2 components which I'm adding to app.component html

When I do this it works as normal:

```
<app-parent></app-parent>
<app-child1></app-child1>
```

Result is:

```
parent works!
child1 works!
```

But when I try this:

```
<app-parent>
  <app-child1></app-child1>
</app-parent>
```

There is no result displayed.

Can the above not be done?

Comment: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/ng-content-content-projection-in-angular/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go in `parent.html` file and add `<app-child1></app-child1>` as a content.